# ESig DSS signature validation always returns INDETERMINATE

Tags: java, digital-signature

I am trying to use European Commission-sponsored Digital Signature Service (DSS) library 5.12.1 to validate electronic signatures of the digitally signed PDF-s and XML-s.

The code I am using is

```
byte[] binaryPdf = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncodedDocument);
CommonTrustedCertificateSource trustedCertSource = new CommonTrustedCertificateSource();
CertificateVerifier cv = new CommonCertificateVerifier();
cv.setAIASource(new DefaultAIASource());
cv.setOcspSource(new OnlineOCSPSource());
cv.setCrlSource(new OnlineCRLSource());
cv.addTrustedCertSources(trustedCertSource);
DSSDocument document = new InMemoryDocument(binaryPdf, shortFileName);
SignedDocumentValidator documentValidator = SignedDocumentValidator.fromDocument(document);
documentValidator.setCertificateVerifier(cv);
UserFriendlyIdentifierProvider userFriendlyIdentifierProvider = new UserFriendlyIdentifierProvider();
documentValidator.setTokenIdentifierProvider(userFriendlyIdentifierProvider);
Reports reports = documentValidator.validateDocument();
```

indicated in the dss-documentation PDF. My application *always* gets the INDETERMINATE indication with subindication NO_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN_FOUND (visible in the Certificate element of the CertificateChain). It doesn't find the trust anchors. When I use the sample application 5.12.1 for signature validation and try to validate the same document, I get the expected TOTAL_PASSED indication. My app has internet access. What I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, I successfully embed all my certs (CA and from my organization) using PAdES-BASELINE-B and I always get the same INDETERMINATE result

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between the sample app and your code.
The sample app comes with a pre-configured list of trusted roots (EU LOTL).
Your code comes with an empty `CommonTrustedCertificateSource` (i.e., no certificate is trusted)

See the [DSS FAQ](https://dss-demo.nowina.lu/doc/dss-documentation.html#_frequently_asked_questions_and_implementation_issues)

> When validating a signature I receive INDETERMINATE/NO_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN_FOUND indication

> The result means the validator was not able to reach a trust anchor when validating the certificate chain of the signature. More likely the issue is caused by the fact you have not configured a trusted certificate source within the used CertificateVerifier. To do it, you need to add trust anchors to the instance of CertificateVerifier you use within DocumentValidator:

So you need to add some certificates to the `CommonTrustedCertificateSource`. If you're only verifying signatures created by yourself, add your CA root/your signing certificate to the trusted source. If you're verifying third-party signatures, the solution is more complex. For example, you could extract all certificated from a PDF and add them to the trusted list before validation